# Proving that $\mathbf{(H-\frac{1}{n}J_n)}$ is indempotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-regression, idempotents

I am trying to show that the matrix $\mathbf{(H-\frac{1}{n}J_n)}$ is idempotent where $\mathbf{H}$ is the Hat-matrix (Projection matrix) of linear regression and $J_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with $1$ in all its inputs.  Taking :

$$\mathbf{(H-\frac{1}{n}J_n)(H-\frac{1}{n}J_n)= HH - H\frac{1}{n}J_n - \frac{1}{n}J_nH + \frac{1}{n}J_n\frac{1}{n}J_n}$$

Now, we know that $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{\frac{1}{n}J_n}$ are idempontent, thus :

$$\mathbf{(H-\frac{1}{n}J_n)(H-\frac{1}{n}J_n)=H-H\frac{1}{n}J_n - \frac{1}{n}J_nH +\frac{1}{n}J_n}$$

How would I continue now in order to show that the given matrix is idempontent ?

Comment: The "hat matrix" should be redefined, It is not a usual name...

Comment: @JeanMarie It is the projection matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix

Comment: @JeanMarie It's $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$, where $X$ is the matrix of regressors. It's called the hat matrix because when you multiply $y$ on the left by it, you get $\hat y$, that is, it *"puts a hat on $y$"*, figuratively.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut Thank you for this precise explanation. Thank you as well to the OP.

Comment: @StubbornAtom The previous part of the exercise wants to show that $I - \frac{1}{n}J_n$ is idempotent. But this is indeed the hat matrix $H$, so I can't work anything around./

Comment: Numerically on an example, the statement is wrong. $H$, however, is of course idempotent, being a projection matrix.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut True, $H$ is idempotent and was also used in my elaboration. If the statement is wrong then the exercise is wrong, which is weird in fact.

Comment: Ok, with the additional requirement that $X$ is square, it works. But then, assuming $X$ has full rank, $H$ is obviously the identity matrix, as $\hat y=y$ (the regression is "perfect", the residual vector is zero), because $\mathrm{span}\, X=\Bbb R^n$. That's the same conclusion as @StubbornAtom above.

Comment: Answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1427733/321264.